# Castle Windsor obtain logger by name

Tags: logging, castle-windsor, log4net

I'm trying to get logger instance by name. Currently I have a legacy project with castle windsor and log4net logging facility. From config file I found out that factory uses root level logger. But it would be much more convenient for me to use different by name loggers.
 Is it possible to implement?
 Thanks.

Comment: This behavior that you're looking for is provided by default in Castle Windsor logging facility. If you need a specific ILogger instance, then inject an ILoggerFactory into your class and use the ILoggerFactory.GetLogger(string name) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess there is no way to obtain logger this way. But I've found some strange way to control level of logging.
For example set logging by assembly name:

```
  <logger name="MyProject.Workers.DBWorker">
     <level value="WARN" />
  </logger>
```

This stricts worker obtained in DBWorker.

PS: This logger could be obtained by type:

```
ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(DBWorker));
```

Comment: this behavior resembles the NLog structure where a logger seems to have a name corresponding to the class that calls the logger.